# prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{2n-1}=\frac{t}{2}ln(\frac{1+t}{1-t})$

Tags: taylor-expansion

in order to prove that  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{2n-1}=\frac{t}{2}ln(\frac{1+t}{1-t})$$
i thought about separating the Logarithm which gives
$$\frac{t}{2}ln(\frac{1+t}{1-t}) = \frac{t}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}t^n}{n} + \frac{t^n}{n}$$
note that the $(-1)^{n-1}$ will simplify all odd terms from the sum
but im stuck and i don't know what to do now to prove that it's equal to :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n}}{2n-1}$$
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y = \ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right).$  Then

$$y' = \frac{2}{1-t^2} = 2(1+t^2+t^4+\cdots).$$

Then

$$y = 2\left(t+\frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^5}{5} + \cdots\right) +C.$$

Since $y(0) = \ln(1) = 0$, we know $C=0$.  So

$$y = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n-1}}{2n-1}.$$

Multipy by $t/2$ and, assuming absolute convergence, you're done.

Comment: thank you !i havn't thought about using derivation XD